# NavigationLinkSet attribute not working for forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase in my Digital Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura, navigation-menu

I'm trying to extend the `navigationMenuBase` interface to build a custom navigation menu in my community (Using Build Your Own template). A requirement I have is I need to be able to display a different menu list to the users based on their role.

So I've been trying to use the `navigationLinkSetId`. I run an initialize function when the aura component loads, to calculate which menu list should be used. However, when I set the `navigationLinkSetId`, it doesn't seem to render, and instead always uses the default menu list.

I've followed the documentation here to understand the [navigationMenuBase](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase/specification) interface

My component is described as:

```
<aura:component extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="CalculateUserRegime">

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialise}" />
  <aura:attribute name="navigationLinkSetId" type="String" />

  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navigation--list">
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.menuItems}" var="item">
        <li class="{!'navigation--list-item' + ' ' + (item.active ? 'navigation--selected-item' : '')}">
          <a class="navigation--link" data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" href="">{!item.label}</a>
        </li>
      </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aura:component>
```

Then in my controller, I am calculating which menu needs to be rendered, then setting the `navigationLinkSetId`.

```
({
  initialise: function (component, event, helper) {
 
    component.set("v.navigationLinkSetId", "My_Custom_Menu_List"); 
  
  }
});
```

I've created the menu list in the UI, and have then run the following SOQL query to find its developer name
`SELECT Id, DeveloperName, MasterLabel FROM NavigationLinkSet`. That gave me the string value of `My_Custom_Menu_List`, hence why I'm attempting to hard code it in at the stage.

What's strange is that I am able to use the default attribute to set the menu list, like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="navigationLinkSetId" type="String" default="My_Custom_Menu_List" />
```

And that correctly sets my custom menu.

Any suggestions on how to correctly use the `navigationLinkSetId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that `navigationLinkSetId` is being set before the `initialise` runs.

To get around this you can dynamically create the navigation bar component

In the code where you want the navigation component to be (for example the theme layout controller):

```
({
  doInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    // dynamically add the navbar

    // use CalculateUserRegime to determine linkSetId
    helper.getUserRegime(cmp, event, helper).then(
      $A.getCallback(function (result) {
        cmp.set("v.linkSetId", result);
        // create NavigationBar component with correct navigationLinkSetId

        //set linkSetId
        var linkSetId = cmp.get("v.linkSetId");
        return $A.createComponent(
          "c:navigationBar",
          { "aura:id": "findableAuraId", navigationLinkSetId: linkSetId },
          function (newCmp, status, errorMessage) {
            // place on the page/layout

            var navBarCmp = cmp.get("v.navBarCmp"); //a region called {!v.navBarCmp}
            navBarCmp.push(newCmp);
            cmp.set("v.navBarCmp", navBarCmp);
          }
        );
      })
    );
  }
});
```